# Navigating Textviews using arrow keys

Tags: android, keyboard, textview

My application has a simple 'About' box.

It has a few clickable TextViews (email addresses, phone nos, addresses) all contained within a relative layout within a ScrollView (To accommodate low res screens).

The device I am testing with (Motorola Charm O.S ver 2.1 update 1) has a regular QWERTY keyboard. The problem I am facing is with the use of the arrow keys.

I want the cursor to move predictably from one clickable field to the next and this is where I need help. On the fields that don't need focus I have set the android:cursorVisible="false".I tried using the android:nextFocus* properties but still don't get the desired behavior.

The cursor gets stuck in the first field and overall the behavior is a bit unpredictable. Any ideas on how to get this done. Right now trapping the keys using code seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())
```

The documentation is a little terse but it's basically what you are looking for.

Comment: I got it working with  TextView.setMovementMethod(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.getInstance()).  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Cool sorry, yeah I didn't know which one you would need, but glad it worked out :)